# rails find_or_initialize to update or create large amount of records

Tags: performance, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopify

In our Rails 3.2.13 app we need to query an API for Order data which has many associciated objects, and then store it in our database. Some records may already exist, so if they exist we want to update, if new then we want to create. We are importing thousands of records at a time.

I've been looking into the activerecord-import gem to help performance optimize this using the import method, and came up with the below code:

```
def add_details(order, tax_lines)
  tax_lines.each do |shopify_tax_line|
    taxlines_updated << Taxline.where(:order_id => order.id).first_or_initialize(
      :price => tax_line.price,
      :rate => tax_line.rate,
      :title => tax_line.title)
  end
  Taxline.import taxlines_updated, :validate => false
end
```

The problem is, if the record already exists then it is not updated, it only updates the attributes if the record is new.

How can I get this to work like: "if found -> update attributes" or "if not found -> new" on each record?

Many thanks!

Comment: were you able to find the answer?

Comment: @Sana Yes, see the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code we ended up using, perhaps not the most efficient but it works:

```
def add_details(shopify_orders)
    tax_lines = []
    shopify_orders.each do |shopify_order|
      shopify_order.tax_lines.each do |shopify_tax_line|
        tax_line = Taxline.where(:order_id => shopify_order.id).first_or_initialize
        tax_line.price = shopify_tax_line.price
        tax_line.rate = shopify_tax_line.rate
        tax_line.title = shopify_tax_line.title
        tax_lines << tax_line
      end
    end
    TaxLine.import tax_lines, :validate => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya. first_or_initialize works that way. Try update_attributes after first_or_initialize.

> Taxline.where(:order_id =>
>   order.id).first_or_initialize.update_attributes!(
>         :price => tax_line.price, :rate => tax_line.rate, :title => tax_line.title)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i do not want to commit the changes within each loop. I just want to set the values and then the Taxline.import will commit them all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The `:synchronize` option might work

```
 def add_details(order, tax_lines)
      taxlines_updated = []
      tax_lines.each do |shopify_tax_line|
        taxlines_updated << Taxline.where(:order_id => order.id).first_or_initialize(
               :price => tax_line.price,
               :rate => tax_line.rate,
                :title => tax_line.title)
      end
      Taxline.import taxlines_updated, :validate => false, :synchronize => taxlines_updated
  end
```

For the gem [docs](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/blob/master/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb)

```
    # * +synchronize+ - an array of ActiveRecord instances for the model
    # that you are currently importing data into. This synchronizes
    # existing model instances in memory with updates from the import.
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I am after. However, I don't want to update the order.id but all of the other values :price, :rate, title. So would I just do this instead `:on_duplicate_key_update => [ :price, :rate, :title]` ? Also, is the first value specified the key used for comparison? Thanks for your help :) Ps. I'm using the activerecord-import gem as it works with Rails 3, but seems to have the same functionality available as ar-extensions gem.

Comment: looked the gem docs, `duplicate_key` won't work in this case as `order_id` is not unique. The `synchronize` option might do the trick. It works for existing objects but you have to test to see if works for a combination of new and existing objects.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately no go. The keys used for synch need to be unique. I've posted an answer with the solution I ended up with. Maybe not the best, but it works. Appreciate your help.